# How to run a post-vagrant-up script with Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am running a Laravel application which uses Homestead for its vagrant box setup. I see that there it looks for a `after.sh` file where you can put custom scripts to run during provisioning, but I don't see any place where I can have it run something on EVERY `vagrant up`. What I would like it to run every time the box loads is `pm2 start [process-name.yaml]`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the following line in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "pm2 start [process-name.yaml]", run: "always"
```

you can add `privileged: true` if you want this to be be run with sudo privilegies

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you.